# How to add jquery Regex validation for checking starting character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-ui

```
var validate = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$/;
```

I am using this validation to enter either numberics or alpha numerics I'm checking the

`Indexof("@") == 0 or # ,%,&` index as well.

But now I need to check

```
 var isAccumMatch = (AccumulationString.indexOf("@") == 0 || AccumulationString.indexOf("#") == 0 || AccumulationString.indexOf("%") == 0 || AccumulationString.indexOf("&") == 0);
                       if(isAccumMatch)
                       {
                          var isAMatch = AccumulationString.length == 5 && validateACMSTR.test(AccumulationString);
                          if(!isAMatch)
                          {
                             alert("Value should be numeric or alpha numeric followed by @,#,&,%");
                             return false;
                          }
                       }
```

Can any body help me out how to validate first character `@,#,%,&` followed by numeric or alpha numeric.

```
User Input : @A234, &5674, %ABC1, #123A
```

Comment: By the way, in case that alert is user-facing, you may have meant, "Value should be @, #, &, or % followed by 4 alphanumeric characters." (The order of "followed by" is what I'm pointing out.)

Comment: +1 Pretty well asked for a regex question! Nice one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^[@#%&][a-ZA-Z0-9]{4}$/.test(AccumulationString)
```

should return the condition value you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you need is `/^[@#%&][a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$/`

Basically you can stick *almost** anything in a character group - which is a bit surrounded by square brackets `[` and `]`.

The characters that have special meaning inside a character group are: `^`, `-`, `]`, and `\`.  These should all be escaped `\` to get their literal meaning.  The hyphen `-` can also be put at the very start or end of the group without needing escaping, but some consider this bad practice as it can be accidentally changed from eg `[0-9AZ-]` to eg `[0-9A-Z]` which has a completely different meaning, while `[0-9AZ\-]` at least gives a clue that the hyphen is meant to be a literal and not part of a range definition.

Comment: Than Spester, what about giving other values like #,%,& is this right?^@#&%[A-Z0-9]{5}$ ?

Comment: @user937194 Sorry, forgot to include those, which of course was your point! Corrected.